# Entity Framework 6 - Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have the following code where I want to add two post entries prior to saving:

```
        ticket.Open();

        var post = new Post
        {
            TicketId = dto.TicketId,
            PostContent = "Ticket status changed to Open",
            IsAutomatic = true
        };

        ticket.AddPost(post);

        post = new Post
        {
            TicketId = dto.TicketId,
            PostContent = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dto.Comments)
        };

        ticket.AddPost(post);


        var notification = Notification.TicketReopened(post);

        _unitOfWork.Complete();
```

A post belongs to a ticket. A notification is for a post.

However I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Notification_Post' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
```

The only way I can fix is by calling `_unitOfWork.Complete()` after adding the first post and then calling it again at the end.

`_unitOfWork.Complete()` simply does the following:

```
    public void Complete()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

However I need to complete the entire transaction as a whole.

How can I fix?

Comment: First guess: don't reuse the `post` variable. But there's too much invisible stuff going on to be really able to help.